# Insertion when both sides are mandatory in entity relationship

Tags: sql, entity-relationship

I am preparing for an exam from databases and there is this one thing that puzzles me. From what I've read both sides of any relationship can be constrained to be NOT NULL. I've seen it in at least 2 books and various articles.

Nobody however explains how to insert values into these tables. As far as I know it is not possible in most databases (with the exception of Oracle) to insert into multiple tables at once. That means that it would be needed to insert into one of the tables first. However at that moment there doesn't exist a corresponding entry in the second table so I cannot reference it which violates the NOT NULL constraint.

Another problem is that it is hard to enforce the relationship from both sides in 1:N or M:N relationship. (I can only think of triggers)

So the question is: Are these relationships really implementable or are they just "theoretical" concept which is not used in real life?

Comment: Did you ever get more information on this?

Comment: @PhillipMartin No, but I believe my assumptions were correct.

Answer (score 0):

To implement a relationship between two entities (tables) in SQL, the primary key of a table (Table1) is make the foreign key in the other table (Table2). If it’s two way mandatory relationship (NOT NULL for both tables) then the entries should be first inserted in Table1 which has the primary key  first and then the entries for the other Table2 containing the primary key of the  Table1 as the foreign key should be inserted. Check this [link](http://technology.amis.nl/2005/03/10/declarative-implementation-of-mandatory-master-detail-relationship-order-must-have-order-lines/) for more details and an example.

Comment: You are talking only about 1:N relationship. it would work as you described, however after the first insertion the database would be in inconsistent state. Here arises another problem which is that it is hard to enforce two way mandatory 1:N relationship in database.

Comment: Yes, Technically the database would be inconsistent state but the NOT NULL constraint is not violated hence it works. For M:N relationship you normalize the relationship during the design phase itself hence you create a link table which holds the relationship. Thus it also doesn't violate the NOT NULL constraint.